# Webhook doesnt give anything with json_encode, returns []

Tags: php

I am trying to receive a shoppy webhook and put it in my database. But there for I am first sending it to the discord webhook using json_encode. To see what the `$_POST` variable contains.

```
function postToDiscord($message, $webhook)
{
    $data = array("content" => $message, "username" => "TEST");
    $curl = curl_init($webhook);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

postToDiscord(json_encode(utf8ize($_POST)), "WEBHOOK WAS HERE");
```

Here is a link to the Shoppy api; [click](https://docs.shoppy.gg/#webhooks). It says it should deliver the information with `$_POST`, but when I use the webhook simulator, I only receive `[]`. Does somebody has a solution for this?

Comment: _“It says it should deliver the information with $_POST”_ - where exactly does it say that?

Comment: Not sure what exactly your problem is from your description, but it sounds like this might simply be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: If I remember correctly, `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` I don't need to add json_encode here?